# Google App Engine datastore-primary key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've created a table in the Google App Engine Datastore. It contains the following `FIELDS(GROUPNAME,GROUPID,GROUPDESC)`. How do I set `GROUPID` as the primary key?

My code is as follows:

```
@Entity

@Table(name="group" , schema="PUBLIC")

public class Creategroup {

    @Basic

    private String groupname;

     @Basic   

    private  String groupid;

    @Basic

    private String groupdesc;



 public void setGroupname(String groupname) {

  this.groupname = groupname;

 }

 public String getGroupname() {

  return groupname;

 }

 public void setGroupid(String groupid) {

  this.groupid = groupid;

 }

 public String getGroupid() {

  return groupid;

 }

 public void setGroupdesc(String groupdesc) {

  this.groupdesc = groupdesc;

 }

 public String getGroupdesc() {

  return groupdesc;

 }

 public Creategroup(String groupname, String groupid, String groupdesc
   ) {

  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.groupname = groupname;

    this.groupid = groupid;

    this.groupdesc = groupdesc;


 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the primary key with the `@PrimaryKey` annotation as described in the [Defining Data Classes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html) documentation.

Comment: You'll also need to add @Persistent to every field you want saved in the datastore, and @PersistenceCapable to the class.  It's all there in the link msw provided.

Comment: hi created jpa application using the following link,"http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html" in that they using @Basic,What i do

Comment: @jason, @Persistent is only needed on fields that are not persistent by default, which is most of them. see http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jdo/types.html for a list of types and their default persistence status

Answer (score 0):

megala, the [page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html) you (tried) to link to in your comment to msw's answer contains the following text that should answer your question.  I think if you read that entire page carefully you'll be able to persist some data successfully.

> A data class must have a public or
>   protected default constructor and one
>   field dedicated to storing the primary
>   key of the corresponding datastore
>   entity. You can choose between 4
>   different kinds of key fields, each
>   using a different value type and
>   annotations. (See Creating Data: Keys
>   for more information.) The simplest
>   key field is a long integer value that
>   is automatically populated by JPA with
>   a value unique across all other
>   instances of the class when the object
>   is saved to the datastore for the
>   first time. Long integer keys use a
>   @Id annotation, and a
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy =
>   GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotation: